# Отправить AT-команду модему Huawei в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, консоль, модемы, serial, at

Имеется 4G модем `Huawei e3372s (МТС 827f)`. Ubuntu видит его как три устройства в `/dev/ttyUSB*`
Серийный порт находится в `/dev/ttyUSB2` (определил командой `cat /dev/ttyUSB2`)
Как выполнить AT-команду `AT^GETPORTMODE`?

**UPDATE1:**  Пробовал `socat - /ttyUSB2`. Мне показалось, что примерно в половине случаев модем никак не отвечает на комманду. Нет-ли какой нибудь программы, выбирающей релевантные данные из потока?

**UPDATE2:** C minicom получилось. Было две проблемы:

- нужно было включить в minicom `local echo` - Ctrl+A E
- после каждой команды нужно нажимать enter. Если не нажать, в терминале всё будет выглядеть так же, но команда выполнится только когда эта кнопка будет нажата

Comment: minicom и ckermit пробовал? В 14.04 точно есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AT команды в интерактивном режиме вводятся с помощью minicom или miniterm.py.
Пользователя, возможно, нужно включить в группу dialout

Comment: Где в minicom вводить команду?

Comment: Так прямо там и вводите в виде AT[и_что_там_дальше]. на просто AT должен ответить OK. AT+CIMI должно вернуть IMEI